# Update JSF Component with Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I know this has been asked many times, but mainly with ajax. I can't use ajax in my project.

I want to create an event on selectOneMenu A and update selectOneMenu B.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="A" binding="#{bean.slmA}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.itemsA}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="B" binding="#{bean.slmB}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.itemsB}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I already used the valueChangeListener with a method that adds elements to itemsB (also onchange ="submit()") but slmB doesn't update.

Should it be updated after adding elements to itemsB list?

Comment: Is it on purpose you're using binding and not value (are you generating the selectOneMenu on the bean)? Can I ask why you can't use ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Without ajax I guess one option would be to use a hidden `commandButton` to do a full request (I'd guess there are other options too):

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="A" value="#{bean.slmA}" onchange="$('#form\\:cb').click()">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.itemsA}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:selectOneMenu id="B" value="#{bean.slmB}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.itemsB}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:commandButton id="cb" ajax="false" style="display: none" value="button" action="#{bean.functionThatFillInformationOfListB()}" />
</h:form>
```

Bean must be at least `@ViewScoped` and `functionThatFillInformationOfListB()` return either void or null. Note I changed `binding` to `value` in the `selectOneMenu`'s, but if you are in fact creating the `selectOneMenu`'s on the bean just disregard that (I think it will still work).